# Instalar pymdeco en django

Tags: python, django, pip

Como puedo instalar pymdeco en django, django lo tengo instalado en un entorno virtual, instale pymdeco en mi maquina atravez de pip pero cuando intento instalar pymdeco con pip en el entorno virtual no puedo usar pymdeco.

Como se instala pymdeco en django

Comment: *pymdeco* parece una librería muy antigua y que igual no funcione correctamente con la versión de Django y Python que tengas instalado. ¿Puedes indicar las versiones de Python y Django y el error que estás obteniendo después de hacer la instalación?

Answer (score 1):

Debes asegurarte de que Django este instalado en el entorno virtual. Luego asegúrate de hacer el `pip install` dentro del mismo entorno virtual.

Por ejemplo en tu interface de comandos entra a tu entorno virtual, asumo que estas usando virtualenv.

```
source tuvirtualenv/bin/activate
```

Ahora para estar seguros que Django este instalado usaremos pip freeze para ver que cosas están instaladas en nuestro entorno.

```
pip freeze
```

Nos debería de mostrar una lista de aplicaciones instaladas en nuestro entorno virtual. Con esto puedes revisar si se ha instalado pymdeco también.